# Change link path of wp_list_categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I output the subcategories of the category Fruit  via this code:

```
<?php  $category = get_category_by_slug('fruit'); 
wp_list_categories('hide_empty=1&depth=1&title_li=&child_of='.$category->term_id); ?>
```

It will output the subcategories correctly.

```
Apples = domain.com/fruit/apples 
Oranges = domain.com/fruit/oranges
```

However, specifically for the Oranges, i would like the link to go to custom page which i created:

> domain.com/orange-page/

and **not** to the default of `domain.com/fruit/oranges`

Is there a way to make a rule within the wp_list_categories to modify the link for that one listing?

Comment: Rename the page to archive-oranges, even then I am not sure it is possible without additional implementation to match it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, in the wordpress codex, the function does exactly what its name states: lists the categories, according to the parameters:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

If you want that, i'd create my own function and declare some relations between your categories and your created pages (by ID please not slug) (use get_permalink(), it is very useful) then output the categories by your chosing.

Idea of Associative array between the categories and pages

```
$preset_pages = Array(
 [55] = > [2559]
);
```

Meaning the category with the ID of 55 would be overwritten by the page with the id 2559.

You have to do your own query with the IDs however, i'm afraid i can think of no other solution.

Comment: Thanks for your realization. After reading your comment i went with a realtime html find and replace plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/real-time-find-and-replace/  which works perfectly.